# UINavigationController in UITabBarController - Go to Top on Tab Selection

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` with five views, one of which has a `UINavigationController` within it.

How can I insure that anytime the tab that contains the `UINavigationController` is selected that it goes to the top view in the `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `UITabViewController` class.  I assume you mean `UITabBarController`.

Set a delegate for your `UITabBarController`.  Give the delegate a reference to the navigation controller.  For example, maybe you will use your application delegate as the tab bar controller's delegate:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UINavigationController *theNavigationController;
```

Make sure you hook up the property, either in your nib or in code.
Then, in the delegate, override the `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` method:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if (viewController == self.theNavigationController) {
        [self.theNavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of comparing with a reference, why not checking the type of the selected viewController by using `[viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]`, then typecasting and executing `popToRootviewController` on the result?

Comment: @Till I gave an answer that fit the question.  It has advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Hey @robmayoff I am not trying to be nitpicking... I just felt that using a reference would be overly complicating this simple task. Still, your solution would and will work totally fine, hence my +1.

Comment: For additional clarification, I used Till's comment to my advantage. The code came out as follows: `if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
    {
        [(UINavigationController*)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }`

Comment: @Till Using a reference is more complicated now, but simpler if he wants to add more behaviors when specific tabs are selected—for example if he later puts a navigation controller in another tab and doesn't want the pop-to-root behavior in that tab.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `UITabBarViewContoller`'s delegate, and implement its `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` so that it calls your `UINavigationController`'s `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` when the `UINavigationController` is selected.